# Header not set - SlimFramework

Tags: php, angularjs, api, cors, slim

I use SlimFramework

When i run my script locali with xampp it works fine.
But i uploaded the script to the server and now it cone the error that the header was not set.

XHR does not allow payloads for GET request.
or change a method definition in settings.

Here the script in angular

```
$rootScope.globals = $cookies.getObject('globals') || {};
    if ($rootScope.globals.currentUser) {
        $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + $rootScope.globals.currentUser.token;
    }

$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
        var restrictedPage = $.inArray($location.path(), ['/login', '/register', '/password']) === -1;
        var loggedIn = $rootScope.globals.currentUser;
        if (restrictedPage) {
            if (!loggedIn) {
                $location.path('/login');
            } else {
                UserService.checkToken($rootScope.globals.currentUser.token)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        if (!response.success) {
                            $location.path('/login');
                        }
                    });

            }
        }
    });
```

---

```
function checkToken(token) {
        return $http.get('api/v1/token').then(handleCallback, handleCallback);
    }
function handleCallback(res) {
        console.log(res);
        return res.data;
    }
```

And here the script with SlimFramework

```
$config['displayErrorDetails'] = true;
$config['addContentLengthHeader'] = false;
$config['determineRouteBeforeAppMiddleware'] = true;

$app = new \Slim\App(["settings" => $config]);
$container = $app->getContainer();

// This is the middleware
// It will add the Access-Control-Allow-Methods header to every request


$app->add(function ($req, $res, $next) {
    $response = $next($req, $res);
    return $response
        ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization')
        ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
});


$app->get('/token', function ($request, $response){
    $token = $request->getHeaderLine('Authorization');
    if($token){
        $db = new DbOperation();
        if($db->checkAuthentication($token)){
            $return = $response->withJson(["success"=> true], 200);
        } else {
            $return = $response->withJson([
                "success"=> false,
                "message"=>'Invalid token'
            ], 403);
        }
    } else {
        $return = $response->withJson([
            "success"=> false,
            "message"=>'Header not set.'
        ], 403);
    }
    return $return;
});
```

Whats my Problem?
Everyone knows?

Thx

UPDATE:
Get request
[image]

The response from API testing

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 27 Mar 2017 11:57:27 GMT
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.30
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
X-Powered-By: PleskLin
```

Comment: Hi, I suppose that http://tuerundraum.kbs02.ch is the server where you deployed your PHP, Am I right?

Comment: Yes its my testing server.
But the Api script and angular is on the same server. Both are on tuerundraum.kbs02.ch

Comment: in angular the calls are made by the browser so is your pc the "origin" calling the server

Comment: Wait it seams your problem is not on the cors side, are you trying to send a body with the GET request? can you post the snippet of the actual http get call?

Comment: No i dont send a Body with get. Only the header Authorization.

Comment: ok that's strange If you can try with the middleware, maybe it consider some more headers

Comment: https://github.com/roselykm/slimjwtauth

Answer (score 1):

if you want to open the api to cors call to every possible origin(test only) try this:

```
$app->add(function ($req, $res, $next) {
    $response = $next($req, $res);
    return $response
        ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization')
        ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
});
```

Or there is this Middleware that do the same: https://github.com/palanik/CorsSlim

Comment: I testet it with an * in the origin, but it dousnt work.
The error is the same.

Comment: can you post in you question the http call that is made by the browser?(you can get it with chrome console). So we can verify all the headers that are sent

Comment: Updated my question on top

Answer (score 1):

If you are not sure what is the header name generated by NG, you can debug the header sent to SLIM. In SLIM, it can be done like this:

```
$headers = $request->getHeaders();
foreach ($headers as $name => $values) {
    echo $name . ": " . implode(", ", $values);
}
```

Im using jquery, I set token in header globally, like this:

```
 $.ajaxPrefilter(function( options, oriOptions, jqXHR ) {
    jqXHR.setRequestHeader("Authorization", sessionStorage.token);
 });
```

That will send a token with a header name:

```
HTTP_AUTHORIZATION
```

To get specific header variable:

```
   $token_array = $request->getHeader('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION');

   if (count($token_array) == 0) {
       $data = Array(
            "jwt_status" => "token_not_exist"
        );  

        return $response->withJson($data, 401)
                        ->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');                   
   }

    $token = $token_array[0];
```